# How can I reduce request quantity to GoogleMaps API with .geocomplete

Tags: jquery, geocomplete

I have text input with "geocomplete" on my web page. Every keyPress event sends request to GoogleMaps API. I would like to change this behavior  in the way that request is sent each 3 character (not each letter) or set delay before request.

I tried to use geocode:beforegeocomelete_search event but it does not work.

```
$("input").geocomplete()
                .bind("geocode:beforegeocomelete_search", function(event, results){
                    if ( $("input").val().length < 4) {
                        throw "At least 3 characters required for request sending";
                    }
                });
```

Do you have any ideas on the matter?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of geocomplete you are using. The version at https://github.com/ubilabs/geocomplete/ has a `trigger()` which you can call when the `input` meets the `length` requirements.

Note: the external lib does not seem to be loading in the snippet for some reason.

```js
let geo = $('.geocomplete');

geo.geocomplete();
geo.on('input', function() {
  let el = $(this);
  
  if (el.val().length > 3) {
    el.trigger("geocode");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ubilabs/geocomplete/master/jquery.geocomplete.min.js"></script>
<input class="geocomplete" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Moreover script sends two requests when 
    el.val().length > 3 . I thought geocoplete handles another events (not 'input') and I tried to handle 'keypress', 'keyup' and other keyboard events (and multiple events) but this had no desired effect. Maybe someone knows which event does geocomplete handle?

Comment: @AntonLifanov Since the snippet wouldn't load the external lib, I couldn't test this very well. Might be worth trying on jsfiddle, plnkr, codepen, etc. Chrome dev tools, inspect element, Event Listeners tab could help us see what event sends the second request.